# Android What's the best way to display several layers of varying types of nested data?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I've read several SO posts and gone through some tutorials and now I'm trying to re-create this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS16W.png However, I'm not sure if what I propose to do is the best way to re-create this layout.

Here's what I'm proposing to do:

I'm working with this well nested JSONArray and JSONObject and vice versa API response (example data: https://jsonblob.com/5525b47ae4b0599c1fbd338b). I was thinking that I would create 3 different types of fragments to show the bullet point data. For example, one fragment would display "High Knees .. 25 yards" Another one could be a hyperlink type like in the case of "Shoulder Shrugs", and the final one would display the chart like the one at the bottom of the image. Since the API response separates data by a title like "Warmup" , "Upper Body Circuit", I was going to create a "block" activity  that could contain the title and its related fragments/bullet point data. All of these "block" activities separated by the horizontal black lines would then be placed in another "full view" activity that would display stacked top to bottom. This "full view" activity would then be stored in another array because there are different dates to swipe through (if you notice at the top, it says Tuesday). Also, for each of these layers, there could be any type of variation and amount of data depending on the API call made. I hope this makes some sort of sense, haha.

Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: I'd say 3 custom views (they could be fragments, I don't think they need to be) inside a LinearLayout in a ScrollView.

Comment: @GabeSechan What would these views contain? A "block" surrounded by top and bottom black bars?

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one activity per screen view in an android app, but can have several fragments per activity. Visual separation of your screen sections does not mean you need to have different fragments per sections in your activity. The reason you would want to use separate fragments is to be able to switch out the content of each fragment independently based on some application logic.

However, - if I understand it correctly - in your case, there is no reason why you would want to use multiple fragments per activity, as all your data is going to be changed as a whole based on the user/calendar day. Therefore, you can just use a single activity, or even better, use one fragment in your activity.

For your reference, [this CodePath guide on Fragments](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments) may help you better understand fragments and how to use them. If you would like to read up on Activities more as well, you can do so on [the android developer guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html).

Comment: With my limited knowledge, I feel like I have to use multiple fragments though. When the data comes in, unlike the Rotten Tomatoes Code Path tutorial, the layout of each "block" of my app will change depending on how the data is structured. This heterogeneity within the data leads me to believe that I need to build a fragment for each use case (bullet, links, graphs) and display it like a list.

Comment: Also, I did go through some of that fragments tutorial earlier, but the "activities" key of my data has an array of things to show , I was thinking... I would like to iterate through the fragments I create... (For example one fragment would be one bullet point line) and display all my created fragments line after line into one activity. But I don't know a good way of doing that, except maybe using a ListView? but then I started reading about inserting fragments into ListViews and the general consensus was that it is a terrible idea to do that.

Comment: You can achieve that by using compound layouts or separate layouts per fragments. Please check out this CodePath Guide and let me know if this is not what you need: http://guides.codepath.com/android/Constructing-View-Layouts

Comment: Thanks for the link, Marta. I'll take a look at this. And thanks for the help!!

Comment: To add to my last comment, for example, you could have a RelativeLayout where you can place every widget in the fragment in any way you please, relative to each other. And what I meant by a compound layout, is you could have a relative layout as a root, and inside of it, you could have two LinearLayout elements for the first two sections, and some other layout type to display the aggregate result on the bottom of the screen.  For that you could use another RelativeLayout or GridLayout, etc. Experiment with your AndroidStudio visual editor to see what's the best match for you.